# How to post a rest Api on form submit in form builder

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, formbuilder, angular2-formbuilder

I have created a form builder api where the admin can create custom web forms and update existing forms without building and deploying.Form creation is working.But I am stuck with form submission logic.How to store the form values to the database.Because all forms are generated dynamically so the values of the form has to be stored in the table dynamically. I am trying to create a Rest  API for a form builder just like orbeon.The technologies  I am using are Spring boot,Java 8 ,Rest Api and Mongodb.